# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGlobalEventTarget' of null

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I was upgrading my project angular version from 4.4.7 to latest. I updated my node.js to the latest( 8.11.1 ) and also angular cli to the latest( 1.7.4 ). Now when I am running my code with npm start here is the full error.

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'getGlobalEventTarget' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGlobalEventTarget' of null
at DomEventsPlugin.EventManagerPlugin.addGlobalEventListener 
(platform-browser.es5.js:2474)
    at EventManager.addGlobalEventListener (platform-browser.es5.js:2405)
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.listen (platform-browser.es5.js:2912)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.listen (animations.es5.js:491)
    at listenToElementOutputs (core.es5.js:9215)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12159)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:12082)
    at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12756)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9861)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
    at DomEventsPlugin.EventManagerPlugin.addGlobalEventListener (platform-browser.es5.js:2474)
    at EventManager.addGlobalEventListener (platform-browser.es5.js:2405)
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.listen (platform-browser.es5.js:2912)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.listen (animations.es5.js:491)
    at listenToElementOutputs (core.es5.js:9215)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12159)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:12082)
    at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12756)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9861)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

Comment: have you tried using `ng serve` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Its compiling in terminal too. But when its loading my app I am getting this error on console.

Answer (score 0):

Please **remove** the angular BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule/NoopAnimationsModule import from the child module.
And include these imports in the Parent Module and you are good to go.

```
//import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
//import { BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [..],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    //BrowserModule,
    //BrowserAnimationsModule,
    //NoopAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class ChildModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I import my custom library into my angular app. The error(TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGlobalEventTarget' of null) was throwing from library build file.

The issue was casuing by the way I import platform-browser in my library(websotrm auto suggestion).

Replace

```
import { BrowserModule } from '../../../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser';
```

with

```
import { BrowserModule } from '/@angular/platform-browser';
```